# playing mp3 stream works well in Emulator but doesn't play on Device

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile

I'm facing this problem. 
I'm using flex && actionscript to play an mp3 stream on the phone.

Code works great and the sound is played when the app is run in the flash builder emulator.

However, when i deploy my app on a mobile device (tried several Android phones) everything is good except the stream doesn't play!

Can you please help me??

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="HomeView"
    creationComplete="view1_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
    >
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        import flash.net.*;
        import flash.media.*;

        private var req:URLRequest;
        private var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(8000, true);
        private var s:Sound;
        private var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

        private  function AudioOn():void
        {
            req = new URLRequest("http://stream2.srr.ro:8000/;stream.mp3");
            s = new Sound(req,context);
            channel=s.play();
        }

        protected function view1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            AudioOn();

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
```

EDIT:

i've added the following event handlers for sound object

```
                            s.addEventListener(Event.ID3, id3);
            s.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, openHandler);
            s.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
```

Put a breakpoint in each handler.:

Results: 
    EMULATOR: `openHandler` gets reached after `s.play()` and `progressHandler` is reached continously.

Android Device: breakpoints in handlers are never reached. There is no exception.

Comment: Are you running in debug mode on the devices... if not do that, are there any errors, do you hit break points in your code where you expect?

Comment: DId you set internet permission for your android manifest app?

Comment: Yes, the entire code behaves the same both in the emulator and the device

Comment: @fmodos yes, internet permission is there

Comment: Ok, @DanDinu I would suggest you to add event listener for the url and sound object, so you can "alert" the responses and see if get any type of error message in the depolyed app.

Comment: @fmodos that's what i'm doing right know i'll get back with results. thanks

Comment: Seeing as how there is no exception I doubt this will matter either but you may want to add a listener for the IO_ERROR event 
            s.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler)

Comment: @DanDinu what about the URLRequest, is it loading?

Comment: @fmodos seems there's an Adobe bug with playing streams on Android devices and haven't been fixed in like 3 years.. :|. There's no workaround Ios works